# Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir

Tags: centos, mariadb, centos7, systemd

a bit of a newbie here so mind my obliviousness. I'm trying to install mariadb on a fresh Centos 7 server, though upon running "systemctl start mariadb.service" I get this malarkey:

> Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

"journalctl -xn" outputs:

> The process /usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir could not be executed and failed.

And "systemctl status mariadb.service" outputs:

> Process: 27729 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
>
> Dec 30 20:37:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[27729]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir: Permission denied

I've checked the file permissions and it seems to be in order... Running from sudo also produces the same result. If anyone has any tips, they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was caused by an issue in the configuration file pointing at "mariadb-prepare-db-dir" while the script seems to be called "mysqld-prepare-db-dir" in Fedora 21

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking for any logs in `/var/log/mysql`?

Then you might have to disable selinux. This can be achieved by editing `/etc/selinux/config`.

Another possibility is to give that file the execute permission via `chmod +x /usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir`.